# How do I fix error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long';

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project manager -web app that allows you to sign in as a member and join different kinds of projects. Members can take part in multiple projects. Project and Member -Entities are connected by a Membership -Entity. Every time a logged in member joins a project a new membership Entity is created.

However I'm having trouble creating a new membership after member clicks Join-button on joinProject.html -page. I keep getting following error message:

```
(type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "saveMembership"
```

The goal is to add logged in member to a project. The new membership can be seen listed on projectDetails.html -page.

I'm using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and JPA. I have a feeling this is something really simple and stupid but I just can't find the problem. :(

If you need to see more code or information I will be happy to provide.

Thank you for your time!

Here is the MembershipCreatorObject-class that I try to use to get the needed data into my controller:

```
public class MembershipCreatorObject {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String jobDescription;

    public MembershipCreatorObject() {
        super();
    }

    public MembershipCreatorObject(String id, String username, String jobDescription) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getJobDescription() {
        return jobDescription;
    }

    public void setJobDescription(String jobDescription) {
        this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value= {"/joinProject/{projectId}"})
    public String joinProject(@PathVariable("projectId") Long urlId, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("mObject", new MembershipCreatorObject());

        model.addAttribute("project", projectRepo.findByProjectId(urlId));

        return "joinProject";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveMembership", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveMembership(MembershipCreatorObject mObject) {

        String id = mObject.getId();

        Long idConverted = Long.parseLong(id);

        String username = mObject.getUsername();

        String description = mObject.getJobDescription();

        Project projectToAdd = projectRepo.findByProjectId(idConverted);

        Member memberToAdd = memberRepo.findByUsername(username);

        Membership membershipToAdd = new Membership(description, memberToAdd, projectToAdd);

        membershipRepo.save(membershipToAdd);

        return "redirect:/projectCatalog";
    }
```

Here is the joinProject -html file.

```
    <h1>Join Project</h1>

    <h4 th:inline="text">Logged in as: [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]</h4>

    <form th:object="${mObject}" th:action="@{saveMembership}" action="#" style="padding: 20px;" method="POST">

        <input th:field="*{id}" />
        <!-- th:value="${project.projectId}" -->

        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />
        <!-- th:value="${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}" -->

        <label>What will you be working on?</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{jobDescription}" style="display: block;" />

        <input type="submit" value="Join" style="display: block; margin-top:10px; width:70px;">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to convert the literal string "saveMembership" to a long, rather than the string representation of a long such as:

```
String str = "12323445664546544564974";
Long lng = Long.parseLong(str);
```

This is my assumption based on the exception stacktrace which states "NumberFormatException: For input string: "saveMembership""

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a html or thymeleaf expert but I think you mistyped something in your html.
I believe that when you clink on `submit`, your code send a `POST` request to `/joinProject/saveMembership` instead of `/saveMembership`. You can easily test in the browser (check what is the URL of the POST request)